# How to get SQL count of the unique concatenated values in my postgresl DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table has two columns which concatenate as 'ab'.  I'd like a count of the unique values from the concatenated columns 'ab', here is what I have so far;

```
initial_db=> SELECT concat(street_num, street_name) AS ab FROM recs limit 5;
     ab     
------------
 21ESSEX RD
 21ESSEX RD
 5AUSTIN ST
 5AUSTIN ST
 5AUSTIN ST
(5 rows)

initial_db=>
```

What I'd like is something like this;

```
count       ab
-----       -----
2           21ESSEX RD
3           5AUSTIN ST
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: look up GROUP BY in any SQL manual. The answer is there.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) as count,
concat(street_num, street_name) AS ab
FROM recs
GROUP BY concat(street_num, street_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`. 
Here a detailed explanation how it works:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-group-by/

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, CONCAT(street_num, street_name) AS ab
FROM recs
GROUP BY ab;
```

Comment: @Brian O'Halloran does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for input and with some minor tweaks and got this to work;

```
SELECT CONCAT(street_num, street_name) AS ab, count(*) FROM recs GROUP BY ab ORDER BY count DESC limit 3;        

ab         | count 
--------------------+-------
 170CENTRE ST       |   213
 1372BRUSH HILL RD  |   206
 600CANTON AVE      |   159
```